# How to setup XADisk (XA enterprise transaction) in JBoss EAP6.1

Tags: jboss, datasource, java-ee-6, xadisk

I want to setup JBoss EAP6.1 to use XADisk in XA enterprise transaction. XADisk  allows file system transactions.

What should I do to setup this as XA  enterprise transaction. XADisk has also `RAR`- resource archive for download on creator homepage.

Later I want to use XADisk and database in one transaction in EJB (JavaEE 6).

So far I've found many examples for configuring JDBC XA-Datasources, but XADisk is not the one.

[link to XADisk homepage](https://xadisk.java.net/)

**EDIT**: Thanks to @Gimby for his hint.

Comment: I'm not familiar with XADisk but from what I can see from the user manual you're making wrong assumptions. What you want to achieve is setup XADisk so interacting with it becomes part of your enterprise transaction - you do not do that by setting up an XA datasource. Datasources are for managing JDBC connections to a database, XADisk is not a database. You might want to confirm that and then change your question.

Comment: oh ok, thank you. I did not know that. And yes t I want to use `XADisk` in EJB together with database transactions. If you wish I accept your comment as an answer and write new question.

Comment: Good, but at this point I become useless to you so don't wait for any further response from me. IMO the documentation is quite poor and I tend to avoid products with poor/no documentation myself.